# Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(name) in Angular 14 while upgrading project

Tags: angular14upgrade

I am upgrading the Angular project from Angular 11 to 14.
First i have upgraded project from Angular 11 to 12 and it build successfully.
Then upgraded Angular 12 to 13 and it also got build successfully.
Then upgraded Angular 13 to 14 and the build started failing due to below error.

**Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(name) in Angular 14 while upgrading project**

Added angular.json screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl2wP.png)

Added error screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nRS6.png)

................................

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).